# jQuery Mobile - fields inside nested list are not submited

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this large form that must be submitted at once. One long page wasn't an option so i decided to separate the sections inside nested lists. Here is what the markup looks like:

```
<form action="/home/index" data-ajax="false" data-transition="pop" id="xmlForm" method="post">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

       <li>
           Section 1
            <ul data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="field1">Field1</label>
                    <input type="text" id="field1" />
                </li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="field2">Field2</label>
                    <input type="text" id="field2" />
                </li>
            </ul>
       </li>

       <li>
           Section 2
            <ul data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="field4">Field4</label>
                    <input type="text" id="field4" />
                </li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="field5">Field5</label>
                    <input type="text" id="field5" />
                </li>
            </ul>
       </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
        <fieldset>
            <button type="submit" data-theme="a" name="submit" value="submit-value">Process Script</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

</form>
```

However, once I click the "Submit" button the only values being submitted is:

```
submit:submit-value
```

The form is ignoring all other fields.
Is it by design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your input elements should have the `name` attribute (i.e. `<input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" />`).

Comment: They actually do, i just missed it when i typed the code above. here is a part of the actual code: 
    <input id = "Installation_PathToInstallConfig" name = "Installation.PathToInstallConfig" type="text" value="C:\SP2010\file.xml" /> By the way, I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  If you look at the DOM JQuery rearranges each sub-list into its own page.  This results in all form fields getting moved outside of the `<form></form>` tags.  This is why they are not included on the submit.

I added the 'form' attribute: `<input type="text" id="field2" form="xmlForm"/>` to all of the form fields.  Now when I submit all of the fields in the sub lists are included.

Comment: The documentation suggests that we should avoid nested lists so I endup creating multiple pages, one form on each. But you came up with an interesting approach. I will try that latter.